# Foreach Data in Field Insert Selected Field from One Database to Another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two (2) databases of **dissimilar** Schematics,

> **db1** migrated from **MSSQL to MYSQL**

and

> **db2** created from *Laravel Migration*.

Here's the challenge:
The tables of db1 do not have `id` columns (Primary Key) like is easily found on db2 tables. So I kept getting the warning message:

```
 Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

So I had to inject the `id` columns on the tables in the **db1**

1. I need to extract fields [*level_name*, *class_name*] from *stdlist* in db1,
2. Create levels (id,level_name,X,Y) on db2
3. classes (id,class_name,level_id) on db2

To throw more light: The **level_id** should come from the already created **levels** table

> I have already succeeded in extracting the first instance using the following snippet:

**First Query to Create Levels**

```
INSERT INTO db2.levels(level_name,X,Y)
SELECT class_name as level_name,1 as X,ClassAdmitted as Y
FROM db1.stdlist
GROUP BY ClassAdmitted;
```

This was successful.

Now, I need to use the newly created `id`s in levels table to fill up *level_id* column in the *classes* table.
For that to be possible, must I re-run the above selection schematics? Is there no better way to maybe join the table column from *db1.levels* to *db2.stdlist* and extract the required fields for the new insert schematics.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me eventually:

First, I picked up the levels from the initial database thus:

```
INSERT INTO db2.levels(`name`,`school_id`,`short_code`)
SELECT name ,school_id,short_code
FROM db1.levels 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY  CAST(IF(REPLACE(name,' ','')='','0',REPLACE(name,' ','')) AS UNSIGNED 
INTEGER) ASC;
```

Then I created a PROCEDURE for the classes insertion

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhileClasses()
BEGIN
SET @Level = 1;
SET @Max = SELECT count(`id`) FROM  db2.levels;
START TRANSACTION;
WHILE @Level <= @Max  DO
    BEGIN
         DECLARE val1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
         DECLARE val2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
         DECLARE bDone TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
         DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT trim(`Class1`)
            FROM db1.dbo_tblstudent 
            WHERE CAST(IF(REPLACE(name,' ','')='','0',REPLACE(name,' ','')) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) =@Level
            GROUP BY `Class1`;
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
         OPEN curs;
         SET bDone = 0;
         REPEAT
            FETCH curs INTO val1;
            IF bDone = 0 THEN 
                SET @classname = val1;
                SET @levelID = (SELECT id FROM db2.levels WHERE short_code=@Level limit 1);
                SET @schoolId = 1;
                    SET @classId = (SELECT `id` FROM db2.classes where class_name = @classname and level_id= @levelID limit 1);
                    
                    IF @classId is null and @classname is not null THEN
                        INSERT INTO db2.classes(class_name,school_id,level_id)
                            VALUES(@classname,@schoolId,@levelID);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
         UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;
         CLOSE curs;
    END;
     SELECT CONCAT('lEVEL: ',@Level,' Done');
    SET @Level = @Level + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
//

delimiter ;

CALL dowhileClasses();
```

With this, I was able to dump The `classes` profile matching the previously created `level_id`s.

> The whole magic relies on the `CURSOR` protocol.
>
> For further details [here is one of the documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I used.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a column for Processed and then do a while exists loop

```
INSERT INTO db2.levels(level_name,X,Y)
SELECT class_name as level_name,1 as X,ClassAdmitted as Y, 0 as Processed
FROM db1.stdlist
GROUP BY ClassAdmitted;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM db2.levels WHERE Processed = 0)
BEGIN 
DECLARE @level_name AS VARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT TOP 1 @level_name=level_name FROM db2.levels WHERE Processed = 0
--YOUR CODE
UPDATE db2.levels SET Processed=1 WHERE level_name=@level_name

END
```

You may need to dump into a temp table first and then insert into your real table (db2.levels) when you're done processing. Then you wouldn't need the Unnecessary column of processed on the final table.

Comment: I believe **Processed** field will have to be added to db2.levels.

As for the location for the code, I don't quite get how to use up the data from the 
`SELECT TOP 1 @level_name=level_name FROM db2.levels WHERE Processed = 0`. Recall that all I need from the previous *levels* pre-run is the `id`

Comment: I Don't know why, but the `WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM db2.levels WHERE Processed = 0)' doesn't run. It gives out an error:

> Unrecognised Statement Type (near WHILE)

Comment: If i understand you correctly you need to insert records into your "Levels" table and then the ID that was generated for that record needs inserted into your "Level_Id" table? is there anything else you need to do with the data? What columns are in each table?

Comment: Yes, you understood me.
The columns of **levels** table are: level_name, shortcode, order_id, timestamps
While the second table (**classes table**) contains
the newly generated levels *id*, class_name, previous_class and so on.

Comment: Your answer pointed me to a deeper direction, which led to eventual solution.
But for the sake of clarity, I am going to post the answer that worked for me.
I think, maybe this would have worked if you took into consideration the fact that some of the tags and keywords mentioned herein have some other dependencies...
For instance, I couldn't get `DECLARE` to work outside a `PROCEDURE`